# Bootstrap Tooltips with changing titles not picking up parameters defined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm using [Bootstrap's Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) on a DIV whose contents are updated via Ajax. I have no control over the DIV, so I have to apply the Tooltip parameters in JavaScript. The tooltip changes based on the Ajax content that is returned. (that's what the titleText var is for)

I cannot figure out why it's not picking up the `placement` and `trigger` parameters. It displays the tooltip at the top and it uses hover instead of manual. Can anyone tell me why?

```
$ajaxDiv.html(data)
        .tooltip('hide')
        .attr('data-original-title', titleText)
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip({ trigger : 'manual', placement : 'bottom' })
        .tooltip('show');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/17m69fjm/1/

```
$('#tooltip').tooltip('destroy');

//## recreated in order to accept changes
//## destroy function have problem
//## https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10740
$('#tooltip')
.attr('title',titleText)
.tooltip({
    placement:'bottom',        
    trigger : 'manual'
});

$('#tooltip').tooltip('show');
```